# Can anyone guide me with a visualization I am trying to put together using js or python?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, css-animations, visualization

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var width = 460
var height = 460

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

// Read data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/11_SevCatOneNumNestedOneObsPerGroup.csv", function(data) {

  // Filter a bit the data -> more than 1 million inhabitants
  data = data.filter(function(d){ return d.value>10000000 })

  // Color palette for continents?
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["Asia", "Europe", "Africa", "Oceania", "Americas"])
    .range(d3.schemeSet1);

  // Size scale for countries
  var size = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1400000000])
    .range([7,55])  // circle will be between 7 and 55 px wide

  // create a tooltip
  var Tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid")
    .style("border-width", "2px")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "5px")

  // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
  var mouseover = function(d) {
    Tooltip
      .style("opacity", 1)
  }
  var mousemove = function(d) {
    Tooltip
      .html('<u>' + d.key + '</u>' + "<br>" + d.value + " inhabitants")
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+20) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
  }
  var mouseleave = function(d) {
    Tooltip
      .style("opacity", 0)
  }

  // Initialize the circle: all located at the center of the svg area
  var node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d){ return size(d.value)})
      .attr("cx", width / 2)
      .attr("cy", height / 2)
      .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.region)})
      .style("fill-opacity", 0.8)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", 1)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover) // What to do when hovered
      .on("mousemove", mousemove)
      .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
      .call(d3.drag() // call specific function when circle is dragged
           .on("start", dragstarted)
           .on("drag", dragged)
           .on("end", dragended));

  // Features of the forces applied to the nodes:
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(width / 2).y(height / 2)) // Attraction to the center of the svg area
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(.1)) // Nodes are attracted one each other of value is > 0
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().strength(.2).radius(function(d){ return (size(d.value)+3) }).iterations(1)) // Force that avoids circle overlapping

  // Apply these forces to the nodes and update their positions.
  // Once the force algorithm is happy with positions ('alpha' value is low enough), simulations will stop.
  simulation
      .nodes(data)
      .on("tick", function(d){
        node
            .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; })
      });

  // What happens when a circle is dragged?
  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.03).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }
  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }
  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(.03);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

})

</script>
```

The link to this visualization can be found here: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/circularpacking_template.html

My goal is to set this visualization within the hole of a doughnut chart. I have searched endlessly through documentation and google searches for python and js. I would like to use react with this because I was thinking this would make it a little easier, or even use python but I think JS offers better resources for such an objective. What I need help with is figuring out how to place this visualization within the hole of a doughnut chart. If anyone has any information that would set me in the right path or a quick explanation it would be greatly appreciated. I am racking my brain here! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I got it, but I will try to help.

Python have a lot of features and is very versatile, and it even have some libs for visualizations. However it's limited about types of charts.
On other hand you have Javascript which have a lot of features for web and friendly plots.  Also you can customize a lot what you need.

I think you need to think about what's the main purpose of your charts and graphs. If what you need it's something simple and objective, Python is going to be the best choice. 
But if you need something more "fancy", customized, with animations and friendly for general users, Javascript is the best fit.
You can also find tons of codes examples in internet that can help you in the beginning, even with React.

My advice: use Python just for back-end processing data and JS for visualization.

Hope this can helps!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am trying to figure out how to put this inside the hole of a doughnut chart. It's like putting a visualization within another visualization. I can't find a thing about this!

Comment: I just realized now you are using D3.js. I think it's a limitation of this lib. Maybe for this you are going to build something by our own or just try another type of chart :)